# Salesforce formula

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm New to salesforce reporting so i'm sure what i'm trying to get might be easy, but i'm not getting the results I want.

Basically I want to be able to extract the HOUR from a date/time field.

I have tried this:
VALUE(MID (TEXT (CREATED_DATE:UNIQUE), 12, 2))

But it gives me an '-' as an output rather then the actual hour.

Any idea as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: [Salesforce SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a better forum for asking very Salesforce-specific questions

Comment: Thank you @identigral! I will look into that!